# eclipse is not starting though suitable already installed

Tags: java, eclipse

when I am trying to open eclipse this message is coming "version 1.4.2_06 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version 1.5 or greater is required" . But I have already installed jdk6 in my laptop.

Comment: are you getting this message after it's opened or it can't even open?

Comment: Is this windows or linux? If it's linux, you need to `sudo update-alternatives --config java`

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between **I have it installed on my machine** and **I have it on my machine**. Make sure your `Path` variable points to the correct JDK.

Go [here](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html) to read more on this subject.